# addEventListener is not triggering my function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, dom-events, html-input

I'm working with a Online Website Colour Scheme Tool, which has to display the result based on which colour we choose for which, but the function is not triggered by `addEventListener("input", fuction_name);`.

I had worked on these kinds of things multiple times but I can't figure the error in this case. Here is the code:

```
var hedbg = document.getElementById("headbg");
var htex = document.getElementById("headtext");
var head = document.getElementsByClassName("ehead")[0];

var conbg = document.getElementById("contbg");
var ctex = document.getElementById("conttext");
var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("econtent")[0];

function trailWeb() {
    console.log(hedbg.value);
    head.style.background = hedbg.value;
    head.style.color = htex.value;
    console.log(hedbg.value);
    cont.style.background = conbg.value;
    cont.style.color = ctex.value;
}

hedbg.addEventListener("input",trailWeb);
```

Comment: What element is `#headbg`?

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

The DOM `input` event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element is changed. If you're using input elements with `type=checkbox` or `type=radio`, the input event should fire when a user toggles the control, but historically, this has not been the case. Try and attach the `change` event instead for elements of these types.